# Div position shifts when adding content

Tags: javascript, positioning, css, text-justify

Following yesterday's issue ( [DOM Equidistant divs with inline-blocks and text justify won't work when inserting through JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12822068/1735214) )  which @Snuffleupagus was kind enough to help me understand, I stumbled into another weird browser behaviour.

Updated fiddle in here: http://jsfiddle.net/xmajox/NUJnZ/

When any kind of content is added (block or inline) to the divs they shift down. When all divs have content, they magically move back into their correct places.

I tried starting them all with some dummy content div and then just changing that children's text but it reacts the same way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to these div's:

```
.rowSample > div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Because these are elements with `display:inline-block` they are aligned as inline elements but have explicit dimensions. For example, `<img>` tags by default have `inline-block` display mode, so to align them inside text you have to specify a desired `vertical-align` property.

Please take a look at the example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a6Hu2/

Comment: OMG!! you're a genius.....thanks so much ....I was beating my head on why it wasn't sitting RIGHT next to the other div....thank you, thank you, thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Keaukraine, you need to add a

```
vertical-align:top;
```

However, you are also going to need some specific code to get this working on Internet Explorer 7 (which in 2012 is still a major browser).

```
/* For IE 7 */
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

See this article for details: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Comment: Yes I also always do this to support IE7 :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Since it's so simple to add the support I will so for this case. I am no longer supporting by default IE < 8 though, fed up with it. :p

Comment: Just depends on the website's audience - people in China still mostly use IE 6! Also, many businesses still run outdated versions of IE so for a b2b site, sadly it's still essential in my opinion. I wish less of my clients were b2b, then I might be able to at least ignore IE 6!